# without giving output parameter in stored procedure getting error the Size property has an invalid size of 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

My stored procedure

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAccDetailInsNew]
(
    @DocNo bigint,
    @DocType char(20),
    @DetailNo smallint,
    @AccountCode varchar(30),
    @FcAmount numeric(12,2),
    @FcCurrency varChar(30),
    @FcExchRate numeric(15,3),
    @Debit numeric(15,3),
    @Credit numeric(15,3),
    @Dc char(10),
    @DebitAdj numeric(15,3),
    @CreditAdj numeric(15,3),
    @Narration varchar(500),
    @FYear nvarchar(10),
    @DocDate smalldatetime)
```

My asp.net code is

```
cmd.Connection = Con;              
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "spAccDetailInsNew";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocNo", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = _je.DocNo;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocType", SqlDbType.Char,20).Value = _je.DocType;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DetailNo", SqlDbType.SmallInt,20).Value = _je.DetailNo;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AccountCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar,30).Value = ddlAccName.SelectedValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FCAmount",SqlDbType.Decimal).Value= Convert.ToDouble(s);
cmd.Parameters["@FCAmount"].Precision = 15;
cmd.Parameters["@FCAmount"].Scale = 3;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FCCurrency", SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value = ddlCurrency.SelectedItem.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FcExchRate",SqlDbType.Decimal).Value= ddlCurrency.SelectedValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Debit",SqlDbType.Decimal).Value= string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDebit.Text) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(txtDebit.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Credit",SqlDbType.Decimal).Value= string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCredit.Text) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(txtCredit.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dc",SqlDbType.Char,10).Value=dc;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebitAdj",SqlDbType.Decimal).Value= 0;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreditAdj",SqlDbType.Decimal).Value= 0;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Narration", SqlDbType.VarChar,500).Value = txtGrdNarration.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar,10).Value = _je.FYear;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocDate", _je.DocDate);

Con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Con.Close();

i++;
```

Comment: Sorry - what exactly is your issue? What is not working? Please elaborate! Also: what does the stored procedure do?? You're just showing the interface - what's the implementation of it??

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@DetailNo", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = _je.DetailNo;

Comment: Getting exception like"string property has invalid size of 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the size @DetailNo

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DetailNo", SqlDbType.SmallInt,20).Value = _je.DetailNo;
```

should be

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DetailNo", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = _je.DetailNo;
```

Comment: Make sure that the data type you declare as parameters in your code, the actual value that you pass and the data type you declare in your stored proc are of similar data types.